# getting exception while creating Bean of AmazonSNS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I want update my aws-java-sdk version to 1.11.335 but getting exception while creating Bean of **AmazonSNS**

**Bean creation code :**

```
@Bean(name = "amazonSnsClient")
    public AmazonSNS amazonSNSClient() {
        AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClient.builder().withRegion(Regions.fromName(snsConfig.getRegion())).build();
        return snsClient;
    }
```

Using class

```
 @Autowired
    @Qualifier("amazonSnsClient")
    private AmazonSNS snsClient;
```

**in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.335</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**getting exception**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<clinit>(AmazonHttpClient.java:149) ~[Server.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:175) ~[Server.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.<init>(AmazonSNSClient.java:251) ~[Server.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder.build(AmazonSNSClientBuilder.java:60) ~[Server.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder.build(AmazonSNSClientBuilder.java:26) ~[Server.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46) ~[Server.jar:na]
```

Comment: did it work with previous sdk version? which version did you use before?

Comment: btw if you want to use the latest version, for now it's a
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.423

also you may want to use the latest version of `httpcomponents` - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6

Comment: @star67 previous version was 1.9.13

Comment: did you try to play around with versions of `httpcomponents` and `sdk`?

Comment: @star67 actually this decency was imported some other service but now we just add this is in own service and getting this exception